# Adding an element to a drop down list which is binded to a database initially

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012, html-select

I am coding in ASP.net using C# in Microsoft Visual Studio. I have a dropdown list that I bind using the smart tag under the "Choose Data Source" on the Default.aspx page.

I have binded it to an ACCESS database. It currently has this data: 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013. I would like to find out a way to insert a word programmatically before the data item 2009 as "Select". So the data items are as follows: Select,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013.

When ever I do this `DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Please Select", "1"));` It keeps adding the "Please Select" keyword every time a user selects an item from the drop down list.
I don't want that to happen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `!IsPostback` on `page_load` to add element to overcome this issue as follows

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
      DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Please Select", "1"));
  }
```

or

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="state" DataValueField="state">
       <asp:ListItem Text="(Select a State)" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I dont think I can use it because whenever an item from the drop down list is selected, it runs an sql query and loads a charts. I mean IsPostBack works fine, but it doesn't add the new item to the list.

Comment: You can use initial value in the dropdown and then use `AppendDataBoundItems="true"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "Please Select");
  }
```

and set AppendDataBoundItems="true"

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="state" DataValueField="state">
</asp:DropDownList>
```